# Join 4 tables using hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

table A:
subsId
transId

table B:
transId,
itemId

table C:
transId,
payId

table D:
payId,
taxId

Table join: A.transId=B.transId, A.transId=C.transId, C.payId=D.taxId

A:B is a 1:many relation

A:C is a 1:1 relation

C:D is a 1:1 relation

Im using SQL to query these four tables and persisting the result in a pojo X.

pojo definition:

```
@Entity
public class X implements Serializable{
  private String transId;
  @Id
  private String itemid;
  private String payId;
  private String taxId;
  private String subsId;
}
```

I dont understand the hibernate annotation mappings to use at all. I am horribly confused between JoinTables, JoinColumns, OneToMany, ManyToOne, OneToOne annotations. Can you suggest the annotations?

Answer (score 1):

With JPA/Hibernate you create a persistence model that reflects your database model in the object world. I don't fully know your schema, but here is a nice explanation about JPA mappings: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships